# Mircro-controller counter overflow and count

Tags: c, timer, counter, microcontroller

say if i have 8 bit timer with clock speed of 20 Mhz. How far does the timer can count without going overflow in how much time. Or how many times it goes overflow in 1 second? i know it can count 255 and goes overflow

Comment: If it is counting at every 1/20Mhz, then every count will be at 50 ns. and it will overflow at every 12.8 ms. But you need to first determine whether the count will be at every tick. Reading the datasheet will give you that information.

Answer (score 2):

The relation between time and frequency is *t = 1 / f*. That will give you the time of one tick of the timer.

Indeed 8 bits give a max value of 255, though it will overflow at the 256th tick. So 256 * the bit time will give the time it takes to until overflow.

Basic maths from there.